# Qual é a diferença principal entre os algoritmos Knuth-Morris-Pratt e Boyer-Moore

Tags: string, algoritmo, grafo, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Eu sei que o **KMP(Knuth-Morris-Pratt)** é utilizado para achar um texto Y em X, tenta definir um padrão em Y, e depois salva este padrão em um vetor. E eu sei também que o **BM(Boyer-Moore)** funciona melhor para palavras pequenas.

Mas qual é a diferença principal em seu funcionamento, qual é melhor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Exemplo funcional** *em inglês*

- [Knuth-Pratt-Morris](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/best-ideas/string-searching/kpm-example.html)
- [Boyer-Moore](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/best-ideas/string-searching/fstrpos-example.html)

**Em uma explicação grosseira**

A abordagem de *Boyer-Moore* é tentar combinar o último caractere do padrão em vez do primeiro com a suposição de que, se não houver correspondência no final, não é necessário tentar combinar no início. Isso permite "grandes saltos", portanto o **BM** funciona melhor quando o padrão e o texto que você procura são semelhantes a "texto natural" (isto é, inglês)

*Knuth-Morris-Pratt* procura as ocorrências de uma "palavra" *W* dentro de uma "string de texto" principal, empregando a observação de que, quando ocorre uma falta de correspondência, a própria palavra incorpora informações suficientes para determinar onde a próxima partida poderia começar, ignorando assim a re-examinação de caracteres anteriormente correspondentes. (Fonte: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm))

Isso significa que o KMP é mais adequado para conjuntos pequenos como o DNA (ACTG)

**De acordo com o criador:**

> O clássico algoritmo de *Boyer-Moore* sofre do fenômeno que tende a não
>   funcionar de forma tão eficiente em pequenos alfabetos como o DNA. A
>   distância de salto tende a parar de crescer com o comprimento do
>   padrão porque as substrings reaparecem freqüentemente. Ao lembrar mais
>   do que já foi combinado, pode-se obter saltos maiores através do
>   texto. Pode-se até mesmo arranjar a "memória perfeita" e, portanto,
>   olhar cada personagem ao máximo, enquanto o algoritmo Boyer-Moore,
>   enquanto linear, pode inspecionar um personagem do texto várias vezes.
>   Essa idéia de se lembrar de mais foi explorada na literatura por
>   outros. Isso sofre com a necessidade de mesas muito grandes ou
>   máquinas de estado.

**Quando utilizar:**

Em teoria, ambos os algoritmos terão um desempenho "semelhante"; KMP fará cerca de 2n comparações na fase de pesquisa e Boyer-Moore fará cerca de 3n comparações na fase de pesquisa no pior dos casos. Em nenhum dos casos, você precisa repetir o pré-processamento quando receber um novo texto.

Mas a resposta real é que você não deve usar nenhum deles prática.

O armazenamento auxiliar linear necessário por ambos os algoritmos leva a um desempenho consideravelmente mais baixo em arquiteturas modernas por causa de todos os acessos de memória extra.

No entanto, as idéias por trás de *Boyer-Moore* e *KMP* sustentam a maioria dos algoritmos de correspondência rápida de cordas. Algo como a "função de falha" de *KMP* é usada por todos os algoritmos de correspondência de cadeias praticamente efetivos que eu conheço; Acontece que você pode calcular uma "função de falha" "subótima" para um padrão *on-the-fly* que ainda lhe dá uma correspondência de tempo linear enquanto apenas precisa de espaço adicional constante. *Boyer-Moore* é mais rápido do que linear no "caso médio" de combinar um padrão fixo contra o ruído aleatório, e isso se dá em muitas situações práticas.

Fontes:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085201/when-would-you-use-kmp-over-boyer-moore)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656160/what-are-the-main-differences-between-the-knuth-morris-pratt-and-boyer-moore-sea)